# use pickle to save dictionary in python

Tags: python, pickle

I have a file `hash_db.pickle` that when I created it I saved a dictionary on it:

```
v = {hash_value:{"file name":file_name,"file size":file_size,"last scanned time":scanned_time}}

{123dfre345:{"file name":calc.pdf,"file size":234,"last scanned time":12:23 24/12/2013}}
{3gcdshj754:{"file name":star.pdf,"file size":10,"last scanned time":10:30 10/10/2013}}
```

so if I want to change from the file only `last scanned time` for `3gcdshj754`

how could I do that?

Comment: May be this will help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11218477/how-to-use-pickle-to-save-a-dict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pickle`.

```
import pickle
d = pickle.load(open('hash_db.pickle', 'rb'))
d['3gcdshj754']['last scanned time'] = '11:30 11/10/2015'
pickle.dump(d, open('hash_db.pickle', 'wb'))
```

But you might find the [`shelve`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html) module a little more convenient than direct use of pickle. It provides a persistent dictionary which seems to be exactly what you want. Sample usage:

```
import shelve
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

# create a "shelf"
shelf = shelve.open('hash_db.shelve')
shelf['123dfre345'] = {"file name": 'calc.pdf', "file size": 234, "last scanned time": datetime(2013, 12, 24, 12, 23)}
shelf['3gcdshj754'] = {"file name": 'star.pdf', "file size": 10, "last scanned time": datetime(2013, 10, 10, 10, 30)}
shelf.close()

# open, update and close
shelf = shelve.open('hash_db.shelve')
file_info = shelf['3gcdshj754']
file_info['last scanned time'] += timedelta(hours=+1, minutes=12)
shelf['3gcdshj754'] = file_info
shelf.close()
```

And that's it.

Comment: but what if I want to read and print all the 'hash_db.shelve' file ?

Comment: @user3832061 : shelf is like a dictionary so the normal dictionary functions apply, e.g. `shelf.keys()`, `shelf.items()`, etc.

Comment: could I use this : shelf = shelve.open('hash_db.shelve')
 strings = re.findall(hash_value,shelf)

Comment: What happened when you tried it? You want to find those keys (hash_value) that match a regex? Something like this might work `[(k,v) for k,v in shelf.items() if re.match(pattern, k)]`. But note that this does not seem useful - there will not be any discernible pattern in a collection of hashes for which a regex will be useful.

Comment: If you have the hash_value, just look it up directly. `shelf[hash_value]` will return the dictionary that contains the file information.

Answer (score 5):

Using pickle is pretty simple, when writing, use

```
dct = {'3gcdshj754': {'file name': 'star.pdf', 'last scanned time': '10:30 10/10/2014', 'file size': '10'}}

import pickle
pickle.dump(dct, open("save.p", "wb"))
```

and then, when reading it, use

```
import pickle
dct_read = pickle.load(open("save.p", "rb"))
```

Note that either time, you have to open the file in binary mode ([`b` flag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8703425/1860929)).

Editing the content is now simple:

```
dct_read.values()[0]["last scanned time"] = '10:10 10/10/2010'
```

---

Alternatively, as @mhawke suggests in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25054373/1860929), you can use [shelve](https://docs.python.org/2/library/shelve.html).

Comment: it gives me an error "dct_read.values(0)['last scanned time'] = '10:10 10/10/2010'
TypeError: values() takes no arguments (1 given)"

Comment: that is perfect thank you ... I want to ask another question if I can. what if I have many entries in the "save.p" file and I want to edit based on thefirst number like '3gcdshj754' which I considered it as a hash value

Comment: @user3832061 Then ask it as another question :)